# Errors threwn from server are not showing in sweet alert in Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular11

I recently updated my app from **Angular 2** to **Angular 11**. Before update whenever an error is thrown from server, it was shown in Sweet Alert modal. But after update errors from server are not showing in sweet alert error modal. Rather, in browser console an error is shown, saying server error.
I think error is not handled properly. But don't know how to fix it.

**Front End**

`

```
deleteChequeInfo(chequeInfo): void {
    let input = new DeleteChequeInfoInput();
    input.id = chequeInfo.id;
    this._chequeInfoService.deleteChequeInfo(input)
    .pipe(finalize(() => this.primengDatatableHelper.hideLoadingIndicator()))
    .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            this.notify.success(this.l('DeletedSuccessfully'));
            this.diractiveBack.emit(null);
        }
    )
}
```

`

**Back End(Error throwing)**

`

```
public async Task DeleteChequeInfo(EntityDto<long> input){

    var chequeInfo = _ChequeInfoRepository.FirstOrDefault(ci => ci.Id == input.Id);

    if (chequeInfo.PaidAmount > 0) {
        throw new UserFriendlyException("Invoice Is Created"); //this is the error throwing from server
    }

    await _ChequeInfoRepository.DeleteAsync(input.Id);
}
```

`

Comment: Show us the code where you catch the error.

Comment: @Bojan Kogoj question updated

Comment: If you throw exception on backend it won't appear as success in Angular. You are listening to `next`, instead of `error` in `subscribe`

Comment: But in Angular 2 if any error threw from back end was automatically shown as alert

Comment: There have been many changes to RxJS since Angular 2.

Comment: so what is the solution for this problem

Comment: Make a stackblitz example and we'll be able to help more - I don't have enough information to help.